# JavaFx in Eclipse on Mac OS

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, java-11, macos-big-sur

Hello I am working on a project for school. I am having a problem using JavaFX in eclipse on my mac. Had the problem in Catalina and now in Big Sur. I will post basic code below as it does not work with anything.

I get the following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
> edu.unlv.mis768.labwork12.MyFirstGUI Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.unlv.mis768.labwork12.MyFirstGUI

Also when I Scroll over the import of JavaFX it says:

The import javafx cannot be resolved

And when I scroll over "Application" it says:

Application cannot be resolved to a type

I am uncertain as to what to do. I am considering just purchasing a windows laptop to use to complete this project.

Suggestions or help would be very much appreciated!!

Code below:

```
package edu.unlv.mis768.labwork12;

import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.*;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")

public class Basics extends Application {
    @Override /* Method in Application class */
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        int sceneWidth = 100, sceneHeight = 150;
        
        Button button = new Button("Fear The Turtle");
        Scene scene = new Scene(button, sceneWidth, sceneHeight);
        primaryStage.setTitle("FX Button");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like there is nothing wrong except (assuming you are using Java 9 or better) maybe you need to add a module-info.java Just pop it under the src or java dir and here is the one I used to get your project going

module Labwork12 {
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.web;
    requires java.logging;
    requires java.desktop;
    opens edu.unlv.mis768.labwork12;
}

Comment: Thank you for responding. I am extremely new to using Java and eclipse. how do I add/create the module-info.java?

Comment: I created a module-info.java and copied over your statements. However, I still get the error: "javafx.fxml cannot be resolved to a module" in the file. I have placed the file under src in my project but it is outside of my package.

Comment: Outside your package is correct.  Next have you added the Javafx jar library files to your project?

Comment: I bought a windows machine last night and now have it running on there. I am still trying to figure out my mac but it is not as straight forward

Comment: I am unsure if I have done this. Is there a way to look it up? I have downloaded Java FX Scene Builder 2.0 downloaded to my machine. I have installed e(fx)clipse from the marketplace

Comment: I think you have everything you need for a basic app

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is nothing wrong except (assuming you are using Java 9 or better) maybe you need to add a module-info.java Just pop it under the src or java dir and here is the one I used to get your project going

```
    module Labwork12 { 
requires javafx.fxml; 
requires javafx.controls; 
requires javafx.graphics; 
requires javafx.web; 
requires java.logging; 
requires java.desktop; 
opens edu.unlv.mis768.labwork12; 
}
```